# Is it possible to attain public ip with MicroK8S

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Is it possible to attain public ip with MicroK8S?
Upon enabling the ingress addon the ip is 127.0.0.1.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. Your microk8s does not magically obtain a public ip like cloudproviders do. There is no external loadbalancer available.

If you just want to have access to services hosted on that k8s environment, take a look at the [ingress plugin](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress) or the [host-access plugin](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-host-access#:%7E:text=A%20new%20local%20network%20interface,1.1%20.) depending on your exact use-case.

You have to keep in mind that public cloud providers have integrations with lots of other services, like load balancers. Usually self hosted kubernetes does not have all that integrations. But you also can use NodePort services, or host network pods to get access to them on specific ports.

But the best way if you want ingress functionality, you probably want to enable the ingress plugin and change some of the configuration.